# Inform AngularJS about an updated model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple angular app like so:
The html:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="content" ng-controller="LeaderboardCtrl">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="fb_ranking in fb_rankings">
            <div class="rank cell">{{fb_ranking.rank}}</div>
            <div class="name cell">{{fb_ranking.name}}</div>
            <div class="score cell">{{fb_ranking.score}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the JS:

```
function change_data(){
    some_data[0].rank = 99;
    var sc = angular.element(document.getElementById('overlay')).scope;
    sc.$apply(function(){
        sc.fb_rankings = some_data;
    });
}

var some_data = [
    {rank: 1, name: 'Boink a doodledo', score: 3000},
    {rank: 2, name: 'Someone else', score: 300},
    {rank: 3, name: 'Donkey', score: 30},
    {rank: 4, name: 'Booger landon', score: 20},
];
    
function LeaderboardCtrl($scope){
    $scope.fb_rankings = some_data;
}
```

Everything works as expected on load. However, I want to update the model `some_data` via code, and not on an event like a click etc. This is because the update to the model is coming through complex Flash and DOM interaction. Using ng-click or another event based directive is not an option.

So, to update the model, I have the change_data function that modifies one property and then tries to get the angular scope and use the $apply function (according to a bunch of tutorials and posts found online.). But when I run `change_data()`, it dies with the following error:
***TypeError: Object function (a,d){v...*** etc.

I have no idea what is wrong here. Or what the error even means.
I have a jsfiddle here using the above code:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2Ahr/1/

Any pointers at all in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function change_data(){
    some_data[0].rank = 99;
    var sc = angular.element("#overlay").scope();
    sc.$apply(function(){
        sc.fb_rankings = some_data;
    });
```

Beware that modifying the scope outside of angular that way is completely wrong, you should only do this for demo purposes and should modify your scope variables inside your `controller`

Comment: Thanks! That works. I clearly overlooked the fact that .scope is a function and needs to be called. I am curious though: why do you say that this is completely wrong? From the Angular documentation it seems that what Angular is doing in the background is call $scope.$apply anyway and not having to call it in a controller is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: It is clearly for separation of concerns and is a design choice. Your application would work fine but it would be terribly difficult to maintain as it grows. Controllers are responsible of the manipulation of `scope`, and if you ever need to run a digest cycle (apart from tests, ofc) that should be in a directive. Plus, `angular.element(xx).scope()` is slow, very.

Answer (score 0):

Calling scope.$apply directly can cause some issues.
It is safer to use a wrapper:

```
// call this method to avoid '$apply already in progress'
$scope.updateScope = function (fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase === '$apply' || phase === '$digest') {
        if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};
```

Then call:

```
sc.updateScope(function(){
    sc.fb_rankings = some_data;
});
```